# duda con reglas de firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, app

estoy haciendo una app y hasta ahora la estuve desarrollando con las reglas abiertas de firebase, o sea que cualquiera podia leer y escribir dentro. Estuve buscando para configurarlas y me surgió una duda. Se puede poner unas reglas para un documento y otras para documentos que están en un nivel posterior a este? no sé si entiende, por eso les pongo el código.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{usuario}/Parejas {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match/{usuario} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
    }
    match/{usuario}/Etiquetas {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
    }
    match/{usuario}/Parejas/{pareja}/Chat {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Como se ve yo puse unas reglas para el nodo {usuario} y también otras para {usuario}/Parejas.
Me imagino que se puede porque no me saltó ningun eror en la consola de firebase pero pregunto igual. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las reglas solo se aplican hacia colecciones , documentos y subcolecciones, por lo tanto, lo que estas haciendo no deberia generarte problemas.

No podes generar reglas a campos especificos dentro de un documento ya que las reglas no son filtros.

Podes leer un poco mas en la doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Answer (score 0):

Perdon pero hablando de eso yo hago lo  mismo pero el create si me funcion pero el delete no ¿a ti si te funciono asi?

```
match /pagos/{year}/pagos/{id} {
allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.alumnoId || 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;

allow delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.alumnoId || 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
```

Comment: Hola, @Marcos. El apartado de respuestas es para responder a la pregunta del usuario no para consultar cuál fue su solución (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Podrías en todo caso comentar en su pregunta. Si ves que tienes algún problema también abrir una nueva pregunta. Saludos.